# TinyMCE - can it have no editable areas?

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

I tried [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/) ([documentation](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration)) and [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) and they both require this kind of code for initialization:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    selector: '.some-div-with-text-inside',
    inline: true,
    fixed_toolbar_container: '.toolbar',
    valid_elements: '*[*]',
    setup: function(editor) {
            // something that happens on setup
    }
});
```

So, basically some selector is required and all DIVs with `.some-div-with-text-inside` class will become TinyMCE's editable areas. The editor will appear in `.toolbar` container.

==========================

What I would ideally like to achieve is an editor that is not attached to any DIV or TEXTAREA and whose functions (like "bold text", "create a link") would work on any content editable area in the document as long as there is some selection made. With [Rangy](https://code.google.com/p/rangy/) exactly this is possible. See demo: http://rangy.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/cssclassapplier.html

In TinyMCE v3 something like this was available:

```
$(function(){
            tinyMCE.init({ mode: "none", theme: "simple" });
            tinymce.execCommand("mceAddControl", false, "myEditableDIV");
});
```

But `mode: "none"` no longer exists in v4 and the second line became `tinyMCE.execCommand("mceAddEditor", false, "myEditableDIV");` now but when there are multiple editable DIVs added this way then **editor appears multiple times inside `.toolbar`**. I'm wondering if there's any way to prevent that?

**I just need 1 editor for all current *and future* DIVs with `contenteditable`.** Some DIVs may be added or removed from the document. I went through every option in their documentation and I couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can't edit DIV or Textarea without attaching tinyMCE, but here is one trick that you can make - you can **HIDE** the editor toolbars and show them only when you **focus** the current DIV or textarea. To achieve this you can use this function:

```
editor.on('focus', function(e) {
        and here show the toolbars
    });
```